# Flash exit fullscreen mode on PrintJob

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer, actionscript-2

I am using a flash image viewer developed with actionscript 2.0 and used only with IE. It uses flash PrintJob to print images.

```
var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
printJob.start()
printJob.addPage(printMc)
printJob.send();
delete printJob;
```

But when PrintJob is invoked at fullscreen mode, print dialog appears and flash player exits fullscreen mode. Is this a security limitation in Flash ? or Is there any workaround to stop exiting fullscreen mode?

*Tested environment*

Browser: IE9

OS : Windows 7 64 bit

Flash Player: 11.1.102.63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine that it's down to the Operating System rather than a unique Flash issue. You can't keep a window in fullscreen mode if it's not the active window; and when you open the Print dialog, that becomes the active window - thus bumping your Flash out of fullscreen mode.

No workarounds that I can think of, because it's not Flash that's controlling this - it's the OS.